# Maximo Anywhere Work Execution Issue - Build all - After reverting back to the original app.xml

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I made some changes on the AW Work Execution app.xml and run build all and got some errors.

Then I copied back the original app.xml and run build.all.
But I'm getting this error. Any ideas what is the root cause/how to fix?
Appreciated your answer.

This is in Maximo Anywhere 7.6.

BUILD FAILED

C:\IBM\Anywhere\MaximoAnywhere\build.xml:130: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\IBM\Anywhere\MaximoAnywhere\anywhere-apps-builder.xml:816: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\IBM\Anywhere\MaximoAnywhere\anywhere-apps-builder.xml:1053:  subtasks failed to find matches
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:551)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:444)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: C:\IBM\Anywhere\MaximoAnywhere\anywhere-apps-builder.xml:816: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\IBM\Anywhere\MaximoAnywhere\anywhere-apps-builder.xml:1053:  subtasks failed to find matches
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:551)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:444)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForEach.executeSequential(ForEach.java:178)
    at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForEach.execute(ForEach.java:254)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:217)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: C:\IBM\Anywhere\MaximoAnywhere\anywhere-apps-builder.xml:1053:  subtasks failed to find matches
    at com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask.processDoc(XmlTask.java:695)
    at com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask.execute(XmlTask.java:661)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
    ... 52 more

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's failing somewhere within the ANT build, blowing up on a missing subtask. The error is related to the applicationdescriptor.xml.

Which ever application you are building may not have the android environment tag within the applicationdescriptor.xml. The applicationdescriptor.xml is found in the application directory for which you are building. Here's the tag I'm using for work execution:

`<android version="7.6">
        <worklightSettings include="true"/>
        <security>
            <encryptWebResources enabled="false"/>
            <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false" ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3"/>
            <publicSigningKey>Replace this text with the actual public signing key of the certificate used to sign the APK, available by using the 'Extract public signing key' wizard.</publicSigningKey>
            <packageName>com.WorkExecution</packageName>
        </security>
        <compressWebResources enabled="true"/>
    </android>`